# HOW-TO resolve "Add-AzureRmVhd : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Tags: azure

I am trying to add a VHD image from my local filesystem to Azure BLOB storage. Whenever I do this after about 6 minutes I get the error "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request". I use the following steps to upload the image (using Azure Resource Manager):

```
PS C:\Users\myuser> Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-0123456789012

Environment           : AzureCloud
Account               : mysuer@outlook.com
TenantId              : aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-0123456789012
SubscriptionId        : aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-0123456789012
SubscriptionName      : MySubscription
CurrentStorageAccount :

PS C:\Users\myuser>
PS C:\Users\myuser> $rgName = "MyResourceGroupName"
PS C:\Users\myuser> $urlOfUploadedImageVhd = "https://myblobaccount.blob.core.windows.net/myvirtualmachine.vhd"
PS C:\Users\myuser>
PS C:\Users\myuser> Add-AzureRmVhd -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Destination $urlOfUploadedImageVhd -LocalFilePath C:\Users\myuser\myvirtualmachine.vhd
MD5 hash is being calculated for the file  C:\Users\myuser\myvirtualmachine.vhd.
MD5 hash calculation is completed.
Elapsed time for the operation: 00:06:29
Creating new page blob of size 136365212160...
Add-AzureRmVhd : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzureRmVhd -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Destination $urlOfUploaded ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmVhd], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.StorageServices.AddAzureVhdCommand
```

I have no idea how to debug this further? I would very much appreciate any help in finding out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your Azure Storage Account type is "Blob Storage". According to docs, it doesn't do page blobs, which are required for VMs.

Fix this by uploading into a General Purpose storage account. More info in [my blog](https://blog.hqcodeshop.fi/archives/350-Microsoft-Azure-The-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-Bad-Request-explained.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Ok, that may be why - but wouldn't it make sense for the Add-AzureRmVhd to check the type of storage and simple issue a warning message? The 400 is not very helpful.

Comment: Jenny: All the relevant information is there:
1) Storage Account is of wrong type
2) How to fix this

What else would you like to see there?

Comment: Yooakim: I agree on your point there. As I don't work for Microsoft, I have no idea why they don't make their error message more informative.

Answer (score 0):

Add -Debug switch to see the actual REST calls.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to try manually uploading a page blob on the azure portal website to find the cause of the issue.
For a VHD you need a page blob. Note that these are not supported on zone redundant storage accounts. More details can be found [here](http://www.tech-coffee.net/understand-microsoft-azure-storage-for-virtual-machines/).